# GCP BigQuery - Run different procedures creating temp tables with same name in a single multi-statement query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Consider two different procedures defined as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp.procedure_example1()
BEGIN

  CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table_proc_1 (_id INT);

  CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_final (_id INT, txt_col STRING);

END;

CREATE PROCEDURE sp.procedure_example2()
BEGIN

  CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table_proc_2 (_id INT);

  CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_final (_id INT, num_col NUMERIC);

END;
```

Each procedure has its own set of instructions, but for the sake of simplicity let's just consider the part that's causing the problem:

- Both create a temporary table called `tmp_final` (in each case the DDL is different)
- None of the procedures have a `DROP` statement for this table

Now, we need to call both procedures in a single multi-statement query, and that's triggering an error. It occurs because BigQuery tries to create the temporary table `tmp_final` twice using the same name for its randomly generated dataset (created for storing temporary tables for 24h. You can check the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/multi-statement-queries#reference_temporary_table))

To replicate the error just create both procedures and run the statement below in the BigQuery console:

```
CALL sp.procedure_example1();

CALL sp.procedure_example2();
```

If both procedures are executed in different sessions, i.e. running the second manually after the first one has finished, this error doesn't happen since the dataset used for storing temporary tables changes across sessions.

I understand that dropping the temporary tables is a good idea for minimizing storage costs, but consider that both procedures are canonic inside the company and can't be changed easily.
Also, the temp tables are often used for log purposes, so to drop them at the end of each procedure should not be our first option.

My question here is: is it possible to force BigQuery to create temporary tables in different datasets when running different procedures? I've tried using transactions, but that didn't work either.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can see a temporary table as a global variable in your session. Therefore, if you can/want to override it, use a `create or replace` statement.

If you want to keep the existing data, you can perform a test on the table existence and perform a append (or merge) if the table exists, or a creation.

If the table is dedicated to the procedure, as a local variable, use a unique name for the table.

Comment: So you're telling me it's not possible to run the procedures as is... we need either to rename the temporary tables or manually run the procs one at a time. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, the procedure do not run in an isolated scope. Because it's global, you have to think the procedure in that way